# Linker command failed with exit code 1 (React native - ios)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, react-native

I'm following along with the [iOS MapView example](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html#ios-mapview-example).

I created a new Objective-C .m file in Project/ProjectFolder/RCTMapManager.m, and added the following code:

```
// RCTMapManager.m
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

#import "RCTViewManager.h"

@interface RCTMapManager : RCTViewManager
@end

@implementation RCTMapManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (UIView *)view
{
  return [[MKMapView alloc] init];
}

@end
```

I then opened up atom and created a js file in components/MapView.js and added the following code:

```
// MapView.js

import { requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native';

// requireNativeComponent automatically resolves this to "RCTMapManager"
module.exports = requireNativeComponent('RCTMap', null);
```

And ran the build command in Xcode to rebuild my previously working project, and the build failed with the error message:

[image]

So I then commented out everything in MapView.js, and commented out the implementation in RCTMapManager.m.

This will build:

```
// RCTMapManager.m
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

#import "RCTViewManager.h"

@interface RCTMapManager : RCTViewManager
@end
```

But as soon as I add the implementation, it fails with "Linker command failed with exit code 1":

```
// RCTMapManager.m
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

#import "RCTViewManager.h"

@interface RCTMapManager : RCTViewManager
@end

@implementation RCTMapManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (UIView *)view
{
  return [[MKMapView alloc] init];
}

@end
```

I wondering why the implementation is causing this to fail, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RCTMapManager is already defined in react-native. I guess the example in the docs has been written before it was added to the library.

If you just want to use maps, have a look at [MapView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/mapview.html).

However if you want to experiment with custom native components, change the class names you use. In Objective-C class names are traditionally prefixed with three letters that describe your company or project (this is where the RCT comes from).